# Php execute lines

Tags: php, mysql

I want to execute these lines When I click on the button:

```
$cijfer = mt_rand(1, 25);
$query = "select word from dba_tblwords where wordId = '$cijfer'";
```

It will pick another word from the database using that query.

The button in the HTML page:

```
echo "<A HREF=$self?n=$n>Play again.</A>\n\n";
```

How can I do this?

Comment: what methods have you tried already? how is your MySQL table set up? can you be any more concise and clear about what you're actually trying to achieve? you need to be concise, you need to be articulate and clear about your aim (in terms of logic) as it's easy for those of us who know *only* what you tell us, to get confused and to be unable to help you .

Comment: If I click on 'echo "<A HREF=$self?n=$n>Play again.</A>\n\n";' I want that it picks another id from the mysql database by this code: '$cijfer = mt_rand(1, 25);
 $query = "select word from dba_tblwords where wordId = '$cijfer'";'

Comment: whats `$self` and `$n` suppose to be?

Answer (score 2):

To actually run the query you can use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). [Here](http://codular.com/php-mysqli) is a good beginners guide.

```
//Connect to database.
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'database');

//The code you provided.
$cijfer = mt_rand(1, 25);
$query = "select word from dba_tblwords where wordId = '$cijfer'";

//Run the query.
$result = $db->query($sql);

//Get the first (and presumably only) row
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

//Output the word.
echo $row['word'];

//Free up some memory.
$result->free();
```

To get the link to work, you need to have the name of the page. You can either hardcode it, or use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`:

```
echo '<a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?n=' . $n . '">Play again!</a>'
```

(I don't know what you use the `$n` for so I just left it in there.)